# Chronological order of events

Tags: meaning-in-context

This describes a certain natural process that takes 15 weeks

It describes what a certain component looks like at some point in time during a naturallly occurring process

What I don't get is if it means it appears this way starting in the third week or after ?

Here's the full sentence

"The malleus first appears as a cartilage model from the third week"

Thanks again for you support guys

Comment: it's a bit vague but my interpretation would be that "from the third week [onward]" would imply that "it" starts at the beginning of the third week and continues through and beyond.

Comment: you can edit your first question, no need for another one.

Comment: You should provide a complete sentence and provide the surrounding context in general. Please see [_Details, Please_](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please).

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 1):

> From the third week

would usually be understood to mean

> from the beginning of the third week

if it was later than the third week, usually

> after the third week

would be used.

"From" starts at a beginning point

> The plane flew from New York to Dallas.
>   *the plane started in New York and finished in Dallas.*

Whatever "it" is should be visible during the third week.